How to change background color of mat-tab-group of Angular?
I am using angular version 16. Here I have a material tab bar of which I want to give a background color. mat-tab-group takes backgroundColor as input and assigns that color.
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary">
    <mat-tab label="Comment">
        <div class="margin-top">
            <app-comp></app-comp>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>   
</mat-tab-group>

In this way I can assign either primary or accent or warn color. Because this input- backgroundColor is of type ThemePalette which is defined in index.d.ts file as -
export declare type ThemePalette = 'primary' | 'accent' | 'warn' | undefined;

So now I want color for say primary-light or my own defiend Pallete. How can I do this? i.e. How to extend that ThemePalette to add more options?
Another way I have tried - I have tried to change background color from css but that did not work
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-group.mat-background-primary .mat-tab-header, 
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar.mat-background-primary .mat-tab-header {
    --mat-tab-header-with-background-background-color: red;
}

So how can I do this? Any way will do - either by extending the ThemePalette or by css.

why not add a class and add style properties to it ? <mat-tab-group backgroundColor="primary" class="something"> and .something{ background-color: 'pink' } ? since it mentioned the backgroundColor property is deprecated

Of course I tried that first but css selectors couldn't change it's background color somwhow. Could you do this this way?

Yes I cloned an example from docs and added a class primary-light ... Here is the link

Well, One thing I would like to mention, I want color only in the nav-bar, not in the body

yeah it is not getting applied for some reason, but I tried this :host ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-tab-header {   background-color: pink; }  and this worked, but again skeptical on ng-deep

Yes, ng-deep could change the background color. Thanks
